# slicing string after space in javascript

Tags: javascript

var data = "Tue Feb 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"

How to slice from the string like?

```
var x = "Tue";
var y = "Feb";
var z = "21";
var t = "2012"
```

Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split on space

```js
var data      = "Tue Feb 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
var [x,y,z,t] = data.split(' ');

console.log(x,y,z,t)
```

This is using destructuring to set the variables

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a limit for only 4 elements.

```js
var data = "Tue Feb 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    array = data.split(' ', 4);

console.log(array);
```

With ES6, you could use a [destruction assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var data = "Tue Feb 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    [x, y, z, t] = data.split(' ', 4);

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split it and not splice. Split your string by space and you get all parts divided by space in to an array.

---

```js
var data = "Tue Feb 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var parts = data.split(" ");
 

var x = parts[0];
var y = parts[1];

console.log(x)
```